# Scrollview hiding the textview text in landscape mode

Tags: android

I am trying to use the scrollview to make the textview wrapped within it scrollable.

I am using the grid layout and am able to position the items as I need to, particularly the long text block, wrapped in a scroll view (the text under the big heading).

However, upon rotating , the long text block disappears completely and I have to keep scrolling it up to make it visible. I need it to be visible as expected when in landscape mode.

[image: Portrait mode- works ok]

[image: landscape mode, text not visible until swiped up]

[landscape mode, now visible after swiping up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI08T.png)

[image: text now visible after swiping up]

**This is my XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/articlesummaryimageview"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/articlesummaryheadingtextview"
        android:layout_below="@id/articlesummaryimageview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/articlesummaryscreenscrollview"
        android:layout_below="@id/articlesummaryheadingtextview"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/showfullarticlebutton"
       >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/articlesummarytextview"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
           />
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/showfullarticlebutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Full Article"

        style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to make your whole layout scrollable or come up with a different design.  To make the whole layout scrollable, put the RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView and set the layout_height for the ScrollView to be wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/articlesummaryscreenscrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
>
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/articlesummaryimageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/articlesummaryheadingtextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/articlesummaryimageview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="26dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/articlesummarytextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/showfullarticlebutton"
    android:layout_below="@id/articlesummaryheadingtextview"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/showfullarticlebutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Full Article"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If your business rules don't allow for the entire layout to be scrollable, what you can do is put your ScrollView as the first layout in the XML and adjust your other views layout_above and layout_below to that initial one (basically making that the view that is always shown and everything else adjust around it).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/articlesummaryscreenscrollview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_above="@+id/showfullarticlebutton"
      android:fillViewport="false"
      >
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/articlesummarytextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"
         />
     </ScrollView>
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/articlesummaryheadingtextview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@id/articlesummaryscreenscrollview"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textSize="26dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      />
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/articlesummaryimageview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@id/articlesummaryheadingtextview"
      android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      />
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/showfullarticlebutton"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="Full Article"
      android:textSize="18dp"
      style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light"
      />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add `RelativeLayout` as a direct child of `ScrollView` and put `TextView` inside it.

**2.** Use attributge `android:fillViewport="true"` to `ScrollView`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/articlesummaryimageview"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/articlesummaryheadingtextview"
        android:layout_below="@id/articlesummaryimageview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/articlesummaryscreenscrollview"
        android:layout_below="@id/articlesummaryheadingtextview"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/showfullarticlebutton">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/articlesummarytextview"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="this is a text"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/showfullarticlebutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Full Article"
        style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light" />
</RelativeLayout>
```